# flutter how to implement animation inside class GetView<Controller>

Tags: flutter, animation, mixins, flutter-getx

I'm starting a flutter project and many people said that GetX is the best state manager framework to use in flutter, so I decide to use it.

I want to do some animation in class HomePage, but when I use mixin SingleTickerProviderStateMixin, it throws a compile error that

```
error: 'SingleTickerProviderStateMixin<StatefulWidget>' can't be mixed onto 'GetView<HomePageController>' because 'GetView<HomePageController>' doesn't implement 'State<StatefulWidget>'.
```

Here is my code

```
class HomePage extends GetView<HomePageController> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  final Duration duration = const Duration(milliseconds: 300);
  AnimationController _animationController;

  HomePage() {
     _animationController = AnimationController(vsync: this, duration: duration);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
     return Container();
  } 

}
```

Because to initialize an AnimationController, it needs an argument named 'vsync', so I have to implement the mixin SingleTickerProviderStateMixin. But because GetView<> doesn't implement State so it throws compile error.

I don't know what is the correct way to implement animation inside GetX, the weird thing is I can't find out any clue or guide for this on Google or any flutter community despite the wide popularity of GetX

Comment: Getx now supports `GetTickerProviderStateMixin`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You want to use `with GetSingleTickerProviderStateMixin` on your controller class, not your actual page. This is specific to GetX and allows you to use animation controllers on stateless widgets.

```
class HomePageController extends GetxController
    with GetSingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  final Duration duration = const Duration(milliseconds: 300);

  AnimationController animationController;

  @override
  void onInit() {
    super.onInit();
    animationController = AnimationController(vsync: this, duration: duration);
  }
}
```

Then in your page that extends `GetView<HomePageController>` access the animation controller with `controller.animationController`.

```
class HomePage extends GetView<HomePageController> 
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
// access animation controller on this page with controller.animationController
     return Container();
  } 

}
```

Just make sure your `HomePageController` is fully initialized before HomePage loads. If `HomePage` is the very first thing in your app, then one way to guarantee that its initialized before `HomePage` tries to load is to initialize the controller with a `Future` method in the GetX class.

```
 Future<void> initAnimationController() async {
    animationController = AnimationController(vsync: this, duration: duration);
  }
```

Then then initialize in your main method.

```
void main() async {
  final controller = Get.put(HomePageController());
  await controller.initAnimationController();

  runApp(MyApp());
}
```

In my experience if you're using an animation controller from a Getx class in the first page that the app loads, initializing in the `onInit` won't guarantee that it'll be ready and might throw an error. Using a `Future` method and `await` in main will ensure you won't get an uninitialized error.

Answer (score 1):

Try use GetX version of `SingleTickerProviderStateMixin` -  [`SingleGetTickerProviderMixin`](https://pub.dev/documentation/get_state_manager/latest/get_state_manager/SingleGetTickerProviderMixin-mixin.html):

```
class HomePage extends GetView<HomePageController> with SingleGetTickerProviderMixin {

}
```

Comment: Thanks for keyword SingleGetTickerProviderMixin, it's what I need. But if implement it on HomePage, it will also throw compile error say that GetView<HomePageController> doesn't implement 'DisposableInterface'. The answer from Loren.A is more correct, implement the mixing in Controller class